# Interact with webpage via webview in Metro

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-metro

Searched all night but can't find an answer, hoping someone can help me out.

I need my VB Metro app to access a webpage and programatically fill in certain fields (e.g. navigate to yahoo mail, programatically fill in username, pwd and press enter.)

I've done it many times before in desktop vb using webbrowser.document.GetElementById("whatever") but it's not an option for metro apps.

So my question is, what is the GetElementById/SetAttribute equivelent for metro?

Thanks in advance!!